# How to calculate points for each question of a Quiz and show their total?

Tags: quiz

I want to build a quiz with points to each question and then sum those points and have a final result.

Example:

#### Question 1?

- A. xxxxxxxx (add 0 points)
- B. xxxxxxx  (add 1 points)
- C. xxxxxxxx (add 2 points)

and it continues to other questions.

Then, in the end I want something like this:

```
Total points: 20
```

(if the points are between)[15-20]: display message !you're awesome

Is this possible to do with Drupal? And how?

Answer (score 0):

The [Quiz module](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) will allow you to set up a quiz in drupal.

> The Quiz module lets you create graded assessments in Drupal. A Quiz is given as a series of questions. Answers are then stored in the database. Scores and results are displayed during or after the quiz. Administrators can provide automatic or manual feedback.

The module has a node type of quiz, which has "Results Feedback" that you could use to score your results. The multiple choice questions also allow you to set the "score if chosen."

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. However, the Quiz module doesn't allow to sum up points , just percentage... do you know another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 7.x-5.x version of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module, you can take advantage of all sorts of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) facilities that are available now. More details on how to get this to work are explained in what follows ...

#### Step 1: Use Max Score related to each question

Navigate to relatie path `node/nid/quiz/questions` in your site (with "`nid`" the node id of the quiz), to list all questions for the selected quiz. Then use the column titled "Max score" to enter the amount of *points* you want to be rewarded for each question.

#### Step 2: Use Rules to calculate the total points

Have a look at this custom rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format):

```
{ "rules_process_all_answers_at_the_end_of_a_quiz" : {
    "LABEL" : "Process all answers at the end of a quiz",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "quiz" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "quiz_result_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "quiz-result:nid" ], "type" : "node" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "integer", "value" : "0" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "total_points" : "Total points" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "quiz_result_answer",
            "property" : "result_id",
            "value" : [ "quiz-result" ],
            "limit" : "100"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "answer_fetched" : "Fetched answer" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "answer-fetched" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "current_answer" : "Current answer" },
          "DO" : [
            { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "For the answer with number [current-answer:number] the points awarded are [current-answer:points-awarded]" } },
            { "data_calc" : {
                "USING" : {
                  "input_1" : [ "total-points" ],
                  "op" : "+",
                  "input_2" : [ "current-answer:points-awarded" ]
                },
                "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "caluclation_result" : "Calculation result" } }
              }
            },
            { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "total-points" ], "value" : [ "caluclation-result" ] } }
          ]
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "The total number of points you earned is [total-points:value]." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This rule will calculate the sum of all *points* earned for each question, and show a set of messages at the end of the quiz which looks similar to this example (in which I used 4 questions):

> For the answer with number 1 the points awarded are 2
>
> For the answer with number 2 the points awarded are 0
>
> For the answer with number 3 the points awarded are 4
>
> For the answer with number 4 the points awarded are 8
>
> The total number of points you earned is 14.

If you have the Rules UI enabled, you should be able to simply import this rule in your own site.

Homework: use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to add an additional Rules Action to display your "*awesome*" message also (based on the value of the `total_points` variable.

***Awesome, no?***

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.